# downgrading the gem coffee-script-source' from 1.9.1 to 1.8.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting this error: ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#indexExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index.

According to others posts that happend because there is a problem with coffee-script-source 1.9.0/1 running on windows so I have to downgrade the gem with the command line: gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'. when I try to do this i get this error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError) Unknown command coffee-script-source,

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Put this line in your gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

And then run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

As cd-rum said
"Put this line in your gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'"
```

and actually run 'bundle update'

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue and I wanted to put a more detailed solution on how to do it and some context to solve this issue: `ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#indexExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index`

#### Changing coffee script's version in the Gemfile

Add in *blog/GemFile* the coffee-script-source v1.8.0 (v1.9.0+ does not work on Windows)

```rb
#For Windows it works with CofferScript v1.8
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Then **Stop the server** (if it was running) and do:

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

It should now be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: ExecJS::ProgramError in Docs#show

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>    this 2 line code create the problem.this code situated in layouts=>application.html.erb.

Solve:

## For Windows it works with CofferScript v1.8

gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

Added this code in Gemfile, and then write in the command line "bundle update coffee-script-source".

https://rubygems.org/gems/coffee-script-source/versions/1.8.0

[image: Picture-1]

[image: Picture-2]