# How to add to gem file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, coffeescript, rubygems

I am getting started on Rails and I am trying to rectify my issue of `"ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home"` while setting up first page as suggested below

[downgrading the gem coffee-script-source' from 1.9.1 to 1.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954935/downgrading-the-gem-coffee-script-source-from-1-9-1-to-1-8-0?answertab=active#tab-top)

But to which gem file should I add? I see a whole of folders under the `GEM PATHS` as shown by the result of the command `GEM ENV`

Also when I run from the command line I get the below error( I assume this is not the way to do it)

```
C:\Sites\myrails\App>gem coffee-script-source 1.8.0
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command coffee-script-source
```

Any help would be really appreciated?

My Rails env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller1.0/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller1.0/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller1.0/Ruby2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/baskaran/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/RailsInstaller1.0/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - C:/Users/baskaran/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\RailsInstaller1.0\Git\cmd
     - C:\RailsInstaller1.0\Ruby2.1.0\bin
     - C:\RailsInstaller1.0\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin
     - C:\RailsInstaller1.0\DevKit\bin
```

As per the suggestion - tried to do the following

```
C:\Sites\myrails\App>gem install coffee-script-source -v 1.8.0
Successfully installed coffee-script-source-1.8.0
Parsing documentation for coffee-script-source-1.8.0
Installing ri documentation for coffee-script-source-1.8.0
Done installing documentation for coffee-script-source after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But still getting the below when trying to access `localhost:3000/pages/home`

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/RailsInstaller1.0/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
```

Comment: Look for a file named `Gemfile` in the rails app directory.

Answer (score 2):

Generally these things are managed via the `Gemfile`. If you need to downgrade:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Then do `bundle install`.

Remember the command you're looking for to do a manual install is:

```
gem install coffee-script-source -v 1.8.0
```

Comment: Tried the gem install command - it ran successfully - I rebooted the rails server but the issue still exists - not sure what am I missing here

Comment: You should probably amend your question with specific details of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved by this editing the  `Gemfile` in my app directory to add

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

and then run

```
bundle install coffee-script-source
```

Thanks